# Grouping related ICommands

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new to C# and this is my first WPF project. I am following [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial) (using their implementation of RelayCommand and attempting to use MVVM. I am implementing a clone of the standard Windows calculator. I would like to find a way to group functionality of similar buttons as what I am doing seems clumsy.

For exmaple, here is my my XAML of three buttons

```
<Button Content="_7" Focusable ="False" Command="{Binding Seven}" Style="{DynamicResource NumberButton}" Margin="0,134,184,129"/>
<Button Content="_8" Focusable ="False" Command="{Binding Eight}" Style="{DynamicResource NumberButton}" Margin="46,134,138,129"/>
<Button Content="_9" Focusable ="False" Command="{Binding Nine}" Style="{DynamicResource NumberButton}" Margin="92,134,92,129"/>
```

Here is the ICommands for those:

```
public ICommand Nine { get { return new RelayCommand(NineExecute); } }
public ICommand Eight { get { return new RelayCommand(EightExecute); } }
public ICommand Seven { get { return new RelayCommand(SevenExecute); } }
```

and the methods:

```
void NineExecute()
{
   NumberPressed("9");
}
void EightExecute()
{
   NumberPressed("8");
}
void SevenExecute()
{
   NumberPressed("7");
}
```

What should I investigate in order to group similar function buttons such as numbers into a single ICommand, with a single method that can determine the sender - while still not putting code behind in the Window class as the article warns against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xlam code for a button (supposing that you defined your data context):

```
    <....DataContext>
        <loc:Commands/>
    </....DataContext>
    <Button Content="_9" 
            Command="{Binding Path=ShowMeABox}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Content}"/>
```

Our dummy command (using `RelayCommand<T>` from the provided link):

```
public class Commands
{
    private static readonly ICommand _showShowBoxCommand = 
        new RelayCommand<string>(str => MessageBox.Show(str));
    public static ICommand ShowMeABox { get { return _showShowBoxCommand; } }
}
```

That's it.

FYI.

1. It's seems that you explicitly specify button size which is generally a bad practice. To position your buttons use stack or wrap panel, or grid/uniformgrid.
2. Read info on styles and templates to increase code reuse.

Example:

```
 <UniformGrid Columns="3" Rows="3">
    <UniformGrid.DataContext>
        <loc:Commands/>
    </UniformGrid.DataContext>
    <UniformGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ShowMeABox}"/>
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Content}"/>
        </Style>
    </UniformGrid.Resources>
    <Button Content="_1"/>
    <Button Content="_2"/>
    <Button Content="_3"/>
    <Button Content="_4"/>
    <Button Content="_5"/>
    <Button Content="_6"/>
    <Button Content="_7"/>
    <Button Content="_8"/>
    <Button Content="_9"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

1. May be it's possible to bind `Enumerable.Range(0,10)` to populate control automatically in the MVVM fashion.

Good luck!

Comment: This helped considerably, my code is now way shorter - Two follow up questions: Is there a reason you use a private member instead of just having the public ICommand property return the new RelayCommand? Path=Content returns "_9" which is not what we want. Can we use StringFormat here in the XAML somehow?

Comment: **FirstQ** If you return a new `RelayCommand` in your getter, it means that each time button is pressed you create a new instance of command. I don't think that it's a reasonable approach even if you don't psychically feel a created overhead. **SecondQ** I don't think so. Just parse your string and pass integer into your function.

Answer (score 2):

Use the CommandParameter property - that way you can bind all of your buttons to the same *Command* but with different *CommandParameter* for each number (ie, the CommandParameter should be an integer representing which button as actually pressed)

Comment: I wouldn't use an integer however, in this case, an enum would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: @JeffMercado Wouldn't writing the enum in XAML be way too verbose?

Comment: @kenny Are you seriously saying that `<Button.CommandParameter><local:Number>Nine</local:Number></Button.CommandParameter>` is better than `CommandParameter="9"`?

Comment: @svick not in this case and the ;) was supposed to indicate I wasn't totally serious.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally write this using a constructor:

```
public YourType()
{
    this.Seven = new RelayCommand( () => NumberPressed("7"));
    this.Eight = new RelayCommand( () => NumberPressed("8"));
    this.Nine = new RelayCommand( () => NumberPressed("9"));
}

public ICommand Nine { get; private set; }
public ICommand Eight { get; private set; }
public ICommand Seven { get; private set; }
```

Note that it may also make sense to use the `CommandParameter`, and a single command.  Many frameworks provide a variation on `RelayCommand`/`ActionCommand`/etc which accept a command parameter, which you can then specify in XAML.  That specific implementation doesn't allow it, but many do, and will map to a method which gets the `CommandParameter` as a parameter directly.